# How to change coordinates precision

Tags: arrays, google-maps-api-3

> I am storing markers coordinates in an array and want to compare these
>   coordinates with an MVC polyline array which has been previously
>   populated. For this comparison i want coordinates in both arrays
>   to be at a maximum 3 decimal places. How should i proceed since the toUrlValue() gives a string representation and i want to actually compare values and not strings.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're using toUrlValue(), just use .lat() and .lon().  Then you can use the toFixed() function to convert to 3dp.  e.g.:

```
lat = myLatlng.lat().toFixed(3);
lon = myLatlng.lng().toFixed(3);
```

Comment: thank you duncan...i didn't come across this method in javascript :)